# How to search for previous revisions using Microk8s etcd instance?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, microk8s

I'm trying to search previous versions of my secrets inside Microk8s etcd instance but the number of revisions change everytime I refresh my screen and I don't know why.

When I try to access an older version I get the error below:

```
etcdctl --endpoints=127.0.0.1:2380 get --rev=9133 -w fields /registry/secrets/default/mysql-test-password
{"level":"warn","ts":"2020-09-14T13:40:08.594Z","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:61","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-8b3e59a8-efd2-4f77-a96f-5ec3c451b9b7/127.0.0.1:2380","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = OutOfRange desc = etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted"}
Error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
```

I also added the configuration on my etcd config file and restarted the service but didn't help:

```
--auto-compaction-mode=periodic
--auto-compaction-retention=72h
```

It seems that every time I refresh my screen the number of revisions increased a lot without doing anything.

```
{"header":{"cluster_id":14841639068965178418,"member_id":10276657743932975437,"revision":15322,"raft_term":7}
```

1 second later

```
student@desktop:~$ etcdctl --endpoints=127.0.0.1:2380 get /registry/secrets/default/mysql-root-password -w json
{"header":{"cluster_id":14841639068965178418,"member_id":10276657743932975437,"revision":16412,"raft_term":7}
```

Have someone faced something like that?

Answer (score 0):

`"etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted."` is not an error, it's an expected message when a watch is attempted to be established at a resource version that has already been compacted.

Something is wrong with your etcd cluster, this is almost certainly not an apiserver problem. There's an alarm you might need to disable.

Also remember that you have to update etcd version to 3.0.11 or later -
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45506.

Take a look: [mvcc-issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58067), [reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader).

Comment: Yeah Malgorzata I stopped compation with `--etcd-compaction-interval` on api-server but the number of revisions are still insanely increasing. Every time I check the secret the revisions changes to 4 numbers ahead, it's like a pattern but can't find what is doing that.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is the version I'm using.

etcdctl version
etcdctl version: 3.4.3
API version: 3.4

Comment: Any changes ? Check if you didn't added another switch for your port under the command section of your container section by mistake. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012694/how-fix-this-error-watch-chan-error-etcdserver-mvcc-required-revision-has-be

Comment: Still unsolved, that happens even if I just create a secret I don't need to have any containers to the revision numbers to increase

Comment: Can you pass  --debug flag to your etcdctl command and share output ?