# I have an RBAC problem, but everything I test seems ok?

Tags: kubernetes, watch, rbac, etcd, argo

This is a continuation of the problem described here ([How do I fix a role-based problem when my role appears to have the correct permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429330/how-do-i-fix-a-role-based-problem-when-my-role-appears-to-have-the-correct-permi))

I have done much more testing and still do not understand the error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "dma" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

UPDATE: Here is another hint from the API server

```
watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
```

I found this thread, but I am working in the current kubernetes
[How fix this error "watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012694/how-fix-this-error-watch-chan-error-etcdserver-mvcc-required-revision-has-be)

My user exists

```
NAME   AGE   SIGNERNAME                            REQUESTOR          REQUESTEDDURATION   CONDITION
dma    77m   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client   kubernetes-admin   <none>              Approved,Issued
```

The clusterrole exists

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"ClusterRole","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"kubelet-runtime"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["","extensions","apps","argoproj.io","workflows.argoproj.io","events.argoproj.io","coordination.k8s.io"],"resources":["*"],"verbs":["*"]},{"apiGroups":["batch"],"resources":["jobs","cronjobs"],"verbs":["*"]}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-16T00:24:56Z"
  name: kubelet-runtime
  resourceVersion: "296716"
  uid: a4697d6e-c786-4ec9-bf3e-88e3dbfdb6d9
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - extensions
  - apps
  - argoproj.io
  - workflows.argoproj.io
  - events.argoproj.io
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

The sandbox namespace exists

```
NAME      STATUS   AGE
sandbox   Active   6d6h
```

My user has authority to operate in the kubelet cluster and the namespace "sandbox"

```
{
    "apiVersion": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "kind": "ClusterRoleBinding",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1\",\"kind\":\"ClusterRoleBinding\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"dma-kubelet-binding\"},\"roleRef\":{\"apiGroup\":\"rbac.authorization.k8s.io\",\"kind\":\"ClusterRole\",\"name\":\"kubelet-runtime\"},\"subjects\":[{\"kind\":\"ServiceAccount\",\"name\":\"dma\",\"namespace\":\"argo\"},{\"kind\":\"ServiceAccount\",\"name\":\"dma\",\"namespace\":\"argo-events\"},{\"kind\":\"ServiceAccount\",\"name\":\"dma\",\"namespace\":\"sandbox\"}]}\n"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-12-16T00:25:42Z",
        "name": "dma-kubelet-binding",
        "resourceVersion": "371397",
        "uid": "a2fb6d5b-8dba-4320-af74-71caac7bdc39"
    },
    "roleRef": {
        "apiGroup": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
        "kind": "ClusterRole",
        "name": "kubelet-runtime"
    },
    "subjects": [
        {
            "kind": "ServiceAccount",
            "name": "dma",
            "namespace": "argo"
        },
        {
            "kind": "ServiceAccount",
            "name": "dma",
            "namespace": "argo-events"
        },
        {
            "kind": "ServiceAccount",
            "name": "dma",
            "namespace": "sandbox"
        }
    ]
}
```

My user has the correct permissions

```
{
    "apiVersion": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "kind": "Role",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1\",\"kind\":\"Role\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"dma\",\"namespace\":\"sandbox\"},\"rules\":[{\"apiGroups\":[\"\",\"apps\",\"autoscaling\",\"batch\",\"extensions\",\"policy\",\"rbac.authorization.k8s.io\",\"argoproj.io\",\"workflows.argoproj.io\"],\"resources\":[\"pods\",\"configmaps\",\"deployments\",\"events\",\"pods\",\"persistentvolumes\",\"persistentvolumeclaims\",\"services\",\"workflows\"],\"verbs\":[\"get\",\"list\",\"watch\",\"create\",\"update\",\"patch\",\"delete\"]}]}\n"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-12-21T19:41:38Z",
        "name": "dma",
        "namespace": "sandbox",
        "resourceVersion": "1058387",
        "uid": "94191881-895d-4457-9764-5db9b54cdb3f"
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            "apiGroups": [
                "",
                "apps",
                "autoscaling",
                "batch",
                "extensions",
                "policy",
                "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
                "argoproj.io",
                "workflows.argoproj.io"
            ],
            "resources": [
                "pods",
                "configmaps",
                "deployments",
                "events",
                "pods",
                "persistentvolumes",
                "persistentvolumeclaims",
                "services",
                "workflows"
            ],
            "verbs": [
                "get",
                "list",
                "watch",
                "create",
                "update",
                "patch",
                "delete"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My user is configured correctly on all nodes

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://206.81.25.186:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: dma
  name: dma@kubernetes
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: dma
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Based on this website, I have been searching for a watch event.

I think have rebuilt everything above the control plane but the problem persists.

The next step would be to rebuild the entire cluster, but it would be so much more satisfying to find the actual problem.

Please help.

FIX:
So the policy for the sandbox namespace was wrong.  I fixed that and the problem is gone!

Comment: Permissions are granted to principals by the presence of Roles/ClusterRoles enumerating those permissions, and then the presence of RoleBindings/ClusterRoleBindings which bind those principals to those Roles/ClusterRoles. You have shown a Role named dma, and a ClusterRole binding binding 3 different service accounts (each named dma, but in different namespaces) bound to a ClusterRole called kubelet-runtime. CRB references CR:kubelet-runtime, while you've shown Role:dma. So there's no relationship between the two things you've shown.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta The first one I show is a clusterrolebinding that binds the clusterrole kubelet-runtime to dma. What permissions do you think I am missing?

Comment: What permissions do you have? You haven't shown cluserrole kubelet-runtime, you've shown a complete unrelated role dma, so it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I have already added that at the top

Comment: Where are you seeing `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "dma" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope`? Running a command? Which one? In logs of some process? Which one? What command did you run to list users? What namespace? What do you mean the user is configured on all nodes, you're showing a kubeconfig file? Why do you have cert info for the SA user? Normally SAs authenticate w/token. I don't think you can just put "dma" in the kubeconfig, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens.

Comment: The policy for sandbox was wrong. After correction everything works as expected.

Comment: In which way are you creating user `dma` ?

Comment: Hi @user3877654, the issue is solved now, could you please post an answer so it will be visible for the community?

Comment: @MikolajS. I am working on a minimal durable solution. When I find it, I will post. There are many possible configurations and I am still learning which ones are important.

Comment: @MikolajS. I am using certificate signing requests per these instructions https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/

Comment: Could you share also a role binding that you used for the role "dma" and service accounts "dma" that you used in the ClusterRoleBinding? Also could you answer the questions from the  AmitKumarGupta? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS.  I am working in a bare-metal cluster version 1.23.0. I implemented RBAC using these excellent instructions https://medium.com/swlh/how-we-effectively-managed-access-to-our-kubernetes-cluster-38821cf24d57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think finally understand RBAC (policies and all).  Thank you very much to members of the Kubernetes slack channel. [These](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wdma/Hippocampus-Analytics/main/manifests/policies.yaml) policies have passed the first set of tests for a development environment ("sandbox") for Argo workflows. Still testing.

`policies.yaml` file:

```yaml
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dev
  namespace: sandbox
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - "*"
    attributeRestrictions: null
    resources: ["*"]    
    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
  - apiGroups: ["argoproj.io", "workflows.argoproj.io", "events.argoprpj.io"] 
    attributeRestrictions: null
    resources:
      - pods
      - configmaps
      - deployments
      - events
      - pods
      - persistentvolumes
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - services
      - workflows
      - eventbus
      - eventsource
      - sensor
    verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dma-dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: dev
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dma
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dma-admin
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dma
  namespace: sandbox
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
  namespace: sandbox
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            run: access
...
```